# Is there a way to call a function before/after each method of a factory/class is executed in Angularjs/javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In java, ruby and many other languages we have a functionality to call a function before/after a method is executed mostly these functionalities are given by frameworks used. Even Jasmine (unit-testing library) has method `beforeEach`(that executes the given block before every `it` block).

Is there a way to do it in Angularjs/javascript, so that it can be executed before calling any method of class or factory ?

Comment: In such cases Javascript provides callback functionality, In angular you can use `.then` or you can write callback function that means it executes after parent method.

Comment: not with my knowledge. You can do it

Comment: Nope, angular or JS does not provide this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your functions in a new function, in order to execute some common operations before and after its execution, see following snippet:

```js
var wrappedFunction = function(fn) {
  return function(){
    console.log("Before execute " + fn.name);
    var retValue = fn.apply(this, arguments);
    console.log("After execute " + fn.name);
    return retValue;
  };
};

function funcTest1(par) {
  console.log("funcTest1 -> Par is: " + par);
};

function funcTest2(param) {
  console.log("funcTest2 -> Param value is: " + param);
};

var funcTest1Wrapped = wrappedFunction(funcTest1);
var funcTest2Wrapped = wrappedFunction(funcTest2);

funcTest1Wrapped("Test1");
funcTest2Wrapped("Test2");
```

I hope it helps you, bye.